# Excel sum across multiple sheets with criteria array

Tags: arrays, excel, sum

I have a workbook with several sheets, each containing a large amount of data formatted identically. What I'd like to do is enter a formula on a summary sheet that sums data from across the data sheets, selecting the data to sum based on an array of criteria.

The list of sheets is named 'AdHoc_Sheets' and the list of criteria is named 'Uncontrollable_Compensation'.

First attempt:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&AdHoc_Sheets&"'!"&"C:C"),A40,INDIRECT("'"&AdHoc_Sheets&"'!"&"E:E")))
```

This works well when only a single criteria (in this case 'A40') is needed. The challenge I'm finding is changing that to be an array of criteria.

Second attempt:

```
 ={SUMPRODUCT(SUM(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&AdHoc_Sheets&"'!"&"C:C"),TRANSPOSE(Uncontrollable_Compensation),0)),0,INDIRECT("'"&AdHoc_Sheets&"'!"&"E:E"))))}
```

Which returns a zero when it's not CSE'd and an #N/A error when it is CSE'd. Something about the dynamics of juggling the arrays is messing me up, and I can't quite tell if I need to turn to MMULT or some other method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What precisely is your new condition, expressed in words? That the value in column C is NOT equal to any of those contained in Uncontrollable_Compensation?

Comment: The opposite, actually - the formula result should be a sum of all values in column E of all sheets in range 'AdHoc_Sheets' where the value in column C of all sheets in range 'AdHoc_Sheets' is present in the range 'Uncontrollable_Compensation'.

Comment: Thanks. Is Uncontrollable_Compensation a vertical or horizontal vector?

Comment: It's set up as a vertical vector, 1 column with 49 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the entries in column C are text, not numeric, **array formula****:

`` =SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&AdHoc_Sheets&"'!"&"C1"),TRANSPOSE(ROW(C1:C100)-MIN(ROW(C1:C100))),0)),Uncontrollable_Compensation,0)),N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&AdHoc_Sheets&"'!"&"E1"),TRANSPOSE(ROW(C1:C100)-MIN(ROW(C1:C100))),0))))` ``

With such a construction you cannot 'get away' with arbitrarily referencing entire columns without detriment to performance. Hence my choice of range from row 1 to row 100, which obviously you can change, though be sure to keep it as small as possible.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: Thanks XOR. Just returns an #N/A error... I'm wondering if it might be to do with the inclusion of 'ISNUMBER', since that forces an array of 'false' when testing the Uncontrollable_Compensation range, which is all text. Mind you, having tried the formula with and without that ISNUMBER function returns an #N/A. Scanning the evaluate formula result... it looks like it's trying to match c1 of the  first sheet, c2 of the second, c3 of the third, all the way up to c7 of the 7th (and last) sheet listed in 'AdHoc_Sheets', with 93 #N/As after that.

Comment: Apologies. I unwisely assumed that AdHoc_Sheets was a horizontal vector. Presume from your comment that it is in fact also a vertical vector?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Both named ranges are set up as vertical vectors.

Comment: Thanks. Have amended in the post. Note that this is now an array (CSE) formula.

Comment: Yes - that works perfectly. I had to increase the range limits from 100 to 20000, but the performance hit is only marginal. Thanks XOR!